# How can i take rows with same id and where status has changed in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, lets call them df1 and df2. I need to make a third dataframe where are rows from df1 filtered with the next conditions:
By comparing the id's of both columns I want the third dataframe to contain the rows and column from df1 where in the df2 rows with same id has different status. I also want the new status as its own column so i can see the old status and the new status

So the dataframes would look something like this:

df1

| id | col1 | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | 1 |
| 2 | 123456 | 1 |
| 3 | 124567 | 1 |
| 4 | 123456 | 1 |
| 5 | 543210 | 1 |

df2

| id | col1 | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234356 | 1 |
| 2 | 1234456 | 2 |
| 3 | 1245567 | 1 |
| 4 | 1234516 | 2 |
| 5 | 5423210 | 2 |

df3(new dataframe)

| id | col1 | status | newstatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 123456 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 123456 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 543210 | 1 | 2 |

So as you can see, third dataframe would have columns and data from the df1 and then the new status from df2 as new column. The rows where id's match but the status has not changed, would be ignored.

I know you can merge the dataframes and then some way compare the columns but is that the wisest way or is some other method easier/better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need append multiple columns from `df2` use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then filter by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df3 = (df1.merge(df2.drop('col1', axis=1).rename(columns={'status':'newstatus'}), on='id')
          .query('status != newstatus'))
```

Or if need append only column `status` use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df3 = (df1.assign(newstatus = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['status']))
          .query('status != newstatus'))
print (df3)
   id    col1  status  newstatus
1   2  123456       1          2
3   4  123456       1          2
4   5  543210       1          2
```

EDIT: Error `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` means there are duplicated `id` values converted to index by `.set_index('id')`:

```
print (df2)
   id     col1  status
0   1  1234356       1
1   2  1234456       2
2   3  1245567       1
3   3  1245567      10 < added duplicated id=3 for test
4   4  1234516       2
5   5  5423210       2
```

First solution use both id:

```
df3 = (df1.merge(df2.drop('col1', axis=1).rename(columns={'status':'newstatus'}), on='id')
          .query('status != newstatus'))
print (df3)
   id    col1  status  newstatus
1   2  123456       1          2
3   3  124567       1         10
4   4  123456       1          2
5   5  543210       1          2
```

For mapping need unique `id`, here is used [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (df2.drop_duplicates('id'))
   id     col1  status
0   1  1234356       1
1   2  1234456       2
2   3  1245567       1
4   4  1234516       2
5   5  5423210       2

print (df2.drop_duplicates('id').set_index('id')['status'])
id
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    2
5    2
Name: status, dtype: int64
```

So now solution working:

```
df3 = (df1.assign(newstatus = df1['id'].map(df2.drop_duplicates('id').set_index('id')['status']))
          .query('status != newstatus'))
print (df3)
   id    col1  status  newstatus
1   2  123456       1          2
3   4  123456       1          2
4   5  543210       1          2
```

Comment: I wonder why this last method does not work. it gives error:
    InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

     also when i tried the upper method, it had more rows than in the df1 which is wrong since i only want the rows where id is same but status has changed